# CSS styling not applying to datetime-local element

Tags: html, css

Trying to override the default width of a `datetime-local` input element but CSS changes are not getting applied to the element.

The `datetime-local` element displays over the sibling element that sits to its right side.

How do you style `datetime-local` elements?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-4">
        <label>System User Account </label>
        <div>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control input-lg" 
                name="sysuseracct" 
                id="sysuseracct" 
                placeholder="Account with issue or request"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
        <label>Date Issue Began</label>
        <div>
            <input 
                type="datetime-local" 
                id="dateissuebegan" 
                name="dateissuebegan" 
                style="height: 2.3rem; font-size: 1em;"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
        <label>External Trouble Ticket</label>
        <div>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control input-lg"
                name="externaltt" 
                id="externaltt" 
                style="padding: 1em;" 
                placeholder="If Applicable"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input { display: inline-block;}
    
#dateissuebegan {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: For the `input` field, in the CSS, did you try to set the `width` property? Also, if you have multiple input elements, and you interested only in styling the `datetime-local` types, you could use the CSS selector `input[type="datetime-local"] { // Your CSS here }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code snippet out.

You can adjust the width to your taste.

```css
input { display: inline-block;}

 input[type="datetime-local"] {
     width: 160px;
     /* More styles here */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="row">

                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        <label>System User Account </label>
                        <div>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="sysuseracct" id="sysuseracct" placeholder="Account with issue or request">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        <label>Date Issue Began</label>
                        <div>
                          <!-- <input type="datetime-local" id="dateissuebegan" name="dateissuebegan" value="2018-06-12T19:30" min="2018-06-07T00:00" max="2018-06-14T00:00"> -->
                          <input type="datetime-local" id="dateissuebegan" name="dateissuebegan" style="height: 2.3rem; font-size: 1em;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-4">
                        <label>External Trouble Ticket</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="externaltt" id="externaltt" style="padding: 1em;" placeholder="If Applicable">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```